# Is it possible to get vim-airline to make the statusline 2 or more lines high?

Tags: statusline, plugin-airline

My statusline has too much information to fit on one line.  It was already marginal, but now that I've rotated my monitor into portrait mode, it's a huge issue.

I really like all the information airline provides, so I really don't want to simplify my configuration.  And I have a lot of vertical space to spare.

So is there a way to split info across multiple lines or configure two airlines I can divide the information across?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! There is no option to change the statusline height (unlike the cmdheight). In my config, I found it useful to define two statuslines (short and long) and commands to toggle the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible. The statusline can only cover one single line. As a hack, you might be able to use the tabline in addition to the statusline to show some information. Airline for example allows to display the statusline in the [tabline as an experimental extension](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/3740312de0be5200286260816e2563e77c0be0c5/doc/airline.txt#L280-L282):

```
* Display the statusline in the tabline (first top line): 
  let g:airline_statusline_ontop = 1
```

Apparently, there also exists an [experimental patch](https://gist.github.com/h-east/3158492#file-vim_multi_statusline-patch), that allows to have a multi-line statusline, but I doubt a bit the general usefulness. Now that we have popup windows available, you can make use of those to display additional information.